# Reduce the number of characters in an SQL function in Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function

I have a function in an Oracle database as following:

```
select c,s,f as f,d as d, v as v from (mysql)
union select c,s,f+(select max(d)-min(d) from mysql)+1 as f,d+(select max(d)-min(d) from mysql)+1 as d,0 as v from (mysql)
union select c,s,f+(select max(d)-min(d) from mysql)+2 as f,d+(select max(d)-min(d) from mysql)+2 as d,0 as v from (mysql)
union select c,s,f+(select max(d)-min(d) from mysql)+3 as f,d+(select max(d)-min(d) from mysql)+3 as d,0 as v from (mysql)
...
union select c,s,f+(select max(d)-min(d) from mysql)+15 as f,d+(select max(d)-min(d) from mysql)+15 as d,0 as v from (mysql)
order by c,s,d
```

There's is limit for function in terms of characters, they shouldn't be more than 1000. I have a particularly redundant part in this function which is:

```
select max(d)-min(d) from mysql
```

Is it possible to replace it with some variable like the ones that I am already using(c,s,f,...)?

I tried approaches like "WITH x AS" but it didn't work. I also searched for similar problems but I couldn't find, probably I am not using the right keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select c,s,f as f,d as d, v as v from (mysql)
UNION ALL
select c,s,f+(select max(d)-min(d) from mysql)+t.r as f,d+(select max(d)-min(d) from mysql)+t.r as d,0 as v 
from (mysql)
CROSS JOIN 
(
SELECT Rownum r
FROM  dual
CONNECT BY Rownum <= 15
) t
```

TRY this solution